# trouble setting a string value

Tags: java, compare

I am working on a project. When I set a String I'd like the setting method to test for a null value. If there is a null value I'd like set the global variable to "purple hotdog". I get an error that says `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to boolean` and I'm not sure why.  Eventually I'd like to call a method that returns a value that encryptedBlock is set to instead of setting the value to "purple hotdog", but baby steps for now. Here is my code, and thanks for the help.

```
private String encryptedBlock = null;

public void setEncryptedBlock(String encryptedBlock) {
    if (this.encryptedBlock.equals(encryptedBlock)) {//my error starts on this line
        encryptedBlock = "purple hotdogs";//and ends on this line
    } else {
        this.encryptedBlock = encryptedBlock;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is proper code:

```
private String encryptedBlock = null;

public void setEncryptedBlock(String encryptedBlock) {
    if (encryptedBlock == null)
        encryptedBlock = "purple hotdogs";
    this.encryptedBlock = encryptedBlock;
}
```

Comment: this.encryptedBlock = "purple hotdogs";

Comment: @brandall why I need this? I'm overriding input value

Comment: I thought it would make it more clear with the lack of { I didn't downvote you by the way!